# Compatible <select> element crossbrowser (IE6 and newer)

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, styles

Is there any way (maybe with jQuery code) to style a select element totally so it will look the same in all major broswers from IE6 and newer?

Feels like select elements is the most difficult form element to solve an unique design for.

Comment: Any design is acceptable if it's the same in all modern browsers + IE>=6?

Comment: Yes, use something other than a select element (such as a ul list) and update the select that is hidden via css.

Comment: `<select>` elements are overused and generally unnecessary. You should probably be using radio buttons or check boxes, with the common exceptions being lists of say countries or states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to leave the form elements as they are. No javascript, no images, no fallback.

I have been through this whole painful process myself and I know from experience that styling form elements is

**a) not worth the time and effort and**

**b) it's not possible**.

The select-element is the most difficult element to style regarding background colour, selected colour, border colour and so on.

You will end up spending many hours if not days for something no one except the designer and client really cares about.

**The web wasn't made to be controlled but to be used by everyone with any browser and any device.**

I wouldn't waste a cent on IE6 but if you do, remember to check all the mobile browsers out there as well. Also consider accessibility for people with disabilities who uses screen readers.

Good luck!

p.s. seriously, don't do it.